# .htaccess file does not affect requested URI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've been working on a small MVC framework based on a routing system, where I check the URI and if the request is registered, and if not it should call a standard-error-route. Therefore I created a `.htaccess` file within my `/public` folder where also the `index.php` file is located, to redirect all requests to my dispatcher.

It worked all fine until I wanted to create some more specific error-pages for example `/error/not-found` or `/error/access-forbidden`. But for some reason, as soon as the requested URI is `/error/` my `.htaccess` does not redirect the request to the index-file anymore, all I get is the `Error 403` because it wants to get into the directory `/error/`, which doesn't exists.

```
#   /mvc/public/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [PT,L]
```

This is the file structure I use

```
/mvc
  /config
    /config-files
  /core
    /Dispatcher.php
    /Repository.php
    /Response.php
    ...
  /src
    /Controller
    /Repository
    ...
  /templates
  /public
    /assets
      /css, js
      .htaccess
      index.php
```

The root of my XAMPP is set to the `/public` directory

So my question is, do I have an Issue in my `.htaccess` file? And if so, could you explain why my current version does not work?

### EDIT

I've withdrawn my Idea of redirecting users to specific error-pages, because it causes more problems than it solves. Now I give the user notifications about the status of the requested resource instead.

I did not found the issue that caused my error 403, but I haven't got it anymore so far.

Comment: I don’t see anything about those specific error pages in your code - so where are they?

Comment: I handle them in my dispatcher, and if I get an error anywhere in my controllers, I redirect the user to such a route @CBroe

Comment: This doesn’t make sense, why would you get a 403 in a 404 situation?

Comment: _“This is the file structure I use”_ - that shows the .htaccess file located inside `/mvc`, whereas your comment above said it was in `/mvc/public/.htaccess` ...

Comment: If I want to redirect the user to `/error/specific-error`, the .htaccess file should redirect the request to my index file, which then calls the dispatcher that takes the URI and checks if the route exist, if the route does not exist the dispatcher calls /error, but if I want to request /error/specific-error, which I registered as a route, the .htacces won't redirect this request. All I get is the 403 Error because it cannot find the Directory / after /error @CBroe

Comment: @CBroe That was a typo, the path to my .htaccess file is as described within my public dir

Comment: Well that sounds more like your dispatcher is messing things up ... please edit your question and include what is actually going on in there. And what do you even mean by “I want to request /error/specific-error” - you are not talking about an _external_ redirect here? (That would make very little sense, redirecting externally on errors is bad practice, and makes clients such as search engines not realize what the status code for the actually requested resources was.)

Comment: @CBroe I'll double check my dispatcher again and edit my question after that.